# How can I do TDD with Joomla 3.2?

Tags: tdd, joomla3.2

I am creating a new component for Joomla 3.2. In my previous component for an older version of Joomla I did not have any unit tests as Joomla was very tightly coupled and complicated.

It is possible to do Test Driven Development with Joomla 3.2?

Answer (score 2):

So far the below PHPUnit bootstrap is working for me.

```
<?php
//TODO: Change this to match your path
$pathToJoomla = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/joomla32";

if (!is_dir(realpath($pathToJoomla))) {
throw new Exception("Could not find the folder: $pathToJoomla");
}

//Fake some required variables

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '';


//start

define('_JEXEC', 1);

// Fix magic quotes.
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', 0);

// Maximise error reporting.
ini_set('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode', '0');
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


if (!defined('JPATH_PLATFORM'))
{
define('JPATH_PLATFORM', realpath($pathToJoomla . '/libraries'));
}
if (!defined('JPATH_LIBRARIES'))
{
define('JPATH_LIBRARIES', realpath($pathToJoomla . '/libraries'));
}
if (!defined('JPATH_BASE'))
{
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath($pathToJoomla));
}
if (!defined('JPATH_ROOT'))
{
define('JPATH_ROOT', realpath(JPATH_BASE));
}
if (!defined('JPATH_CACHE'))
{
define('JPATH_CACHE', JPATH_BASE . '/cache');
}
if (!defined('JPATH_CONFIGURATION'))
{
define('JPATH_CONFIGURATION', JPATH_BASE);
}
if (!defined('JPATH_SITE'))
{
define('JPATH_SITE', JPATH_ROOT);
}
if (!defined('JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR'))
{
define('JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR', JPATH_ROOT . '/administrator');
}
if (!defined('JPATH_INSTALLATION'))
{
define('JPATH_INSTALLATION', JPATH_ROOT . '/installation');
}
if (!defined('JPATH_MANIFESTS'))
{
define('JPATH_MANIFESTS', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/manifests');
}
if (!defined('JPATH_PLUGINS'))
{
define('JPATH_PLUGINS', JPATH_BASE . '/plugins');
}
if (!defined('JPATH_THEMES'))
{
define('JPATH_THEMES', JPATH_BASE . '/templates');
}
if (!defined('JDEBUG'))
{
define('JDEBUG', false);
}

// Import the platform in legacy mode.
require_once JPATH_PLATFORM . '/import.legacy.php';

// Force library to be in JError legacy mode
JError::setErrorHandling(E_NOTICE, 'message');
JError::setErrorHandling(E_WARNING, 'message');

// Bootstrap the CMS libraries.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

//TODO: you will need to adjust this to match your paths
$srcPath = realpath("../../src");
JTable::addIncludePath($srcPath.'/site/tables');
require_once $srcPath."/site/models/base.php";
```

A few more details can be found on [my blog post](http://row1.info/5-developers/290-tdd-with-joomla-3-2.html).